# Can DART application be hosted in a webserver like Apache?

Tags: dart

I am under the impression that a DART program cannot be hosted in a webserver. Could someone please enlighten me on this?

Comment: Why is this closed? Seems like a legit (though a little shallow) question

Comment: absolutely legit question! since dart runs server-side too

Comment: Dart is very very new!!! This is a legit question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can (although that's not its primary use case).

From [Google Plus, 28th Feb 2013](https://plus.google.com/u/0/105677827480893940108/posts/NKwfTtm28gd):

> Finally I managed to make Dart work in Apache CGI ! I didn't find any information about this, so I tryed by myself. Here is how I did it (Apache 2.2, and Ubuntu) ...

From [news.dartlang.org, 26th May, 2012](http://news.dartlang.org/2012/05/run-dart-in-apache-web-server.html)

> Today, Sam McCall announced mod_dart: the ability to run Dart apps embedded in Apache! Just like PHP, Perl, Python, and many other scripting languages, you can now use Dart to power your server-side web apps from inside the Apache web server.

Both these are "proof of concepts", but they show that Dart can be embedded within a web server such as Apache.

Now the "but..."

Although it's proven that Dart can be embedded within a webserver, Dart is more like node.js, in that the server side dart binary provides a VM for an application to use.  That application *could* include its own webserver, for example:

```dart
main() {
  var server = new HttpServer();

  server.addRequestHandler(
     (req) => true,   // matcher - should this function handle this request?
     (req, res) {     // handler - what should happen when this request matches?
       res.outputStream.write("${req.method}: ${req.path}"); // eg: GET: /foo
       res.outputStream.close();
     });

  server.listen('127.0.0.1', 8080);
```

Answer (score 1):

Example Apache CGI in Dartlang 2.3:

Copy "dartaotruntime" to "/var/www/your-site/cgi-bin"

$ chown apache:apache dartaotruntime

Create a file test.cgi

```
#!/bin/sh

BASE=/var/www/your-site/cgi-bin
$BASE/dartaotruntime $BASE/test.aot
```

$ chmod 0755 test.cgi

$ chown apache:apache test.cgi

Create a file test.dart

```
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> args) {
        Map<String, String> envVars = Platform.environment;
        print("Content-Type: text/html\n");

        String input = "";
        if (envVars['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                var content_length = int.parse(envVars['CONTENT_LENGTH']);
                while(input.length < content_length) {
                        input += stdin.readLineSync();
                }
        }
    print("""
<html>
<form method="post" action="test.cgi">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<p><strong>ENV:</strong> {$envVars}</p>
<p><strong>INPUT:</strong> {$input}</p>
</html>""");
}
```

$ dart2aot test.dart test.aot

$ chown apache:apache test.aot

Run the cgi: https://www.your-site.com/cgi-bin/test.cgi

Answer (score 1):

You can run dart like a perl script using cgi-bin apache environment. I test it on my Mac with XAMPP and **it works**:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/dart
import 'dart:io';
void main() {
    Map<String, String> envVars = Platform.environment;
    print("Content-Type: text/html\n");
    String input = "";
    if (envVars['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        var content_length = int.parse(envVars['CONTENT_LENGTH']);
        while(input.length < content_length) {
            input += stdin.readLineSync();
        }
    }
    print("""
        <html>
        <form method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <p><strong>QUERY_STRING:</strong> ${envVars['QUERY_STRING']}</p>
        <p><strong>ENV:</strong> {$envVars}</p>
        <p><strong>INPUT:</strong> {$input}</p>
        </html>
        """
    );
}
```

Initially some errors appeared in the error_log, the xampp libraries were not working. I just had to copy from the place indicated in the log to the lib directory of xampp and it works normally.

> ==> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log <== [Sun Feb 23 14:08:12.799968 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 91112] [client 127.0.0.1:64109]
>   AH01215: dyld: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_bind_blob64:
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/dart.dart
>
> [Sun Feb 23 14:08:12.800332 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 91112] [client
>   127.0.0.1:64109] AH01215:   Referenced from: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/Versions/A/BaseBoard:
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/dart.dart
>
> [Sun Feb 23 14:08:12.800432 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 91112] [client
>   127.0.0.1:64109] AH01215:   Expected in: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libsqlite3.dylib:
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/dart.dart
>
> [Sun Feb 23 14:08:12.800529 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 91112] [client
>   127.0.0.1:64109] AH01215:  in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/Versions/A/BaseBoard:
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/dart.dart
>
> [Sun Feb 23 14:08:12.800581 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 91112] [client
>   127.0.0.1:64109] End of script output before headers: dart.dart

I used these commands to update the libraries:

```
ln -s `which dart` /usr/local/bin/dart
sudo cp /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework//Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libJPEG.dylib 
sudo cp /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework//Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/
sudo cp /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework//Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/
sudo cp /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/
```

Take a look on result using QueryString and Post:

[image]

Do not forget to set the correct path to dart executable on the first line of script. I usually link it to /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 0):

The mod-dart has been stalled for development for 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that these days - as opposed to the outdated original answer - server side dart is absolutely a thing. The way to do this is run a dart server side app using something like [Alfred](https://github.com/rknell/alfred) and then using a reverse proxy pass the data through, that way you can use SSL from Lets Encrypt. I personally use Nginx to do it following a guide like this:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

Subbing out nodejs for my dart app.